# PHP mail() function has stopped working

Tags: php, email, sendmail, mailer

I have been developing a Web app with the MAMP solution stack (v2.0.5), which includes:

- Mac OS X (v10.7.3)
- Apache v2.2.21
- MySQL v5.5.9
- PHP v5.3.6

I have been using the PHP `mail()` function to send an activation URL to newly registered user accounts:

```
$body = "Thank you for registering. To active your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
$body .= BASE_URL . 'activate.php?x=' . urlencode($e) . "&y=$a" . "&z=$bs";
mail($trimmed['email'], 'Registration Confirmation', $body, 'From: admin@tester.com');
```

However, it seems that after a while... this has just stopped, and now I fail to receive any of these these messages to my tester user accounts.

My `php.ini` file is at: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini

With the default settings:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =
```

It used to work perfectly until recently and has now failed. I haven't intentionally changed any settings that I am aware of that may have caused this to stop.

After much Googling and reading it seems you have to set up your SMTP server in order to send emails from your localhost to another email address for it to work at all, but I am very positive that it did used to work, I received emails... honestly!

I hope someone can help. Many thanks.

**UPDATED-SOLVED:** 
Basically sorted it. Started trying to use PEAR and the Mail plugin, but found it horrible. Ended up using an external SMTP server and PHPMailer, much better.

Useful Info: 
http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html
https://orangsetya.wordpress.com/2007/09/12/send-mail-using-smtp-authentication-phpmailer-script

Comment: Well you had to use some server as relay (that is, localhost in your case) to send your emails. Maybe that server got blacklisted due to spam?

Comment: Did you check your spam box? I had this issue on an ec2 instance - creating an SPF DNS Record resolved the issue

Comment: When you say relay server, are you saying that some SMTP server on my Mac acted as the means to send these emails via localhost originally? And now has been potentially blacklisted at the destination mail servers?

Comment: Based on your update, thought I would add my 2 cents. PEAR sucks. I try to avoid it at all costs.

Comment: I completely agree! I was experiencing much pain with uncontrollable error messages: http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=9950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically sorted it. Started trying to use PEAR and the Mail plugin, but found it horrible. Ended up using an external SMTP server and PHPMailer, much better.

Useful Info: http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html https://orangsetya.wordpress.com/2007/09/12/send-mail-using-smtp-authentication-phpmailer-script

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new script with the mail command and hard code the values in as strings, to see if you are recieving the emails. Also check to see if any updates to your OS has made any modifications to your apache/php install.

Try a simple script like this:

```
<?php
    mail('youremail@example.com', 'My Subject', 'My Message');
?>
```

Comment: As I've been using the MAMP environment I'm under the impression that neither Apache or PHP should have updated or changed with a Mac OS X update. I've reinstalled MAMP (non Pro) but that hasn't made a difference. I also used old scripts I had from backups prior to this and they aren't working either, emails send to two different destination domains.